# CRM Dynamics 2013: A record required by this process could not be found

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to build a OOTB workflow in CRM Dynamics 2013, although I get the above mentioned error message when I try.

`A record required by this process could not be found.(Cannot create a lookup without the required parameters.)`

My workflow basically is trying to assign a team to a record when its created. My workflow definition is showed below.

[image: Error Message Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a guessing that error is occurring when the workflow is actually run.

I think your mapping is wrong, it looks like you are trying to assign the record owner, to the team who already own the record. If that team isn't set (which it presumably isn't, and that's why you are assigning it) then you are likely to get `A record required by this process could not be found`.

Your mapping needs to reference a field that is populated.

Comment: so what do you suggest I do, should I set the Team first on the form in a field(using JavaScript perhaps), I though it would set the owner in the workflow , as the owner field on the form has a lookup to either team/user, I need the workflow to set the current logged in users team as the owner of the record when saving the record.